# Set specific GPG key for specific recipient in mutt

Tags: mutt, gpg

I'm trying to make `mutt` use a specific GPG key when sending mails to a specific recipient, much like "per-recipient rules" in `OpenPGP / Enigmail`. For example, if I want to send an email to `coworker@company.com` I want to encrypt it with the public key `0xDEADBEEF` and when I send an email to `loveydovey@home.net` I want to encrypt it with some other public key `0xBA5EBA11`.

To this end, I include the following lines in my `~/.mutt/muttrc` file:

```
send-hook '~t ^coworker@company\.com$' 'set crypt_autoencrypt ; set crypt_autosign'
crypt-hook '~t ^coworker@company\.com$' '0xDEADBEEF'
send-hook '~t ^loveydovey@home\.net$' 'set crypt_autoencrypt ; set crypt_autosign'
crypt-hook '~t ^loveydovey@home\.net$' '0xBA5EBA11'
```

The `send-hook` works as expected, but I still always have to pick the key. How can I make `mutt` choose the key as defined by `crypt-hook`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crypt-hook`'s pattern is a recipient, so remove `~t` from the pattern, it's not needed:

```
crypt-hook '^coworker@company\.com$' '0xDEADBEEF'
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to skip the confirmation question ('Use keyID ... ?') without any patches?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.